# How to change an FTP host user/password with FtpWebRequest?

Tags: .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

Is this possible? Or what is the best way to do so in a .NET application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *on the server*, it depends on the FTP software.  If it's Windows-hosted and integrated with Windows security, you'd have to change the username/password through Windows (possibly Active Directory, etc.)  If it's some other off-the-shelf FTP software, then it depends on how they deal with passwords.